# Resolving the root of a webapp from getResource

Tags: java, tomcat, classloader

I have a file structure like this in my webapp:

```
webapp/
├── META-INF
└── WEB-INF
    ├── reports
    │   └── info.txt
    └── web.xml

3 directories, 2 files
```

I need to get `/WEB-INF/reports/info.txt` from a class like so:

```
this.getClass().getResource("/WEB-INF/reports/info.txt");
```

Will this resolve? I'm going to test it, but I'm not sure how Tomcat's classloader resolves things. If this doesn't work, how can I get the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first of all, `this.getClass().getResource` should not work (though I didn't try). It's not a classpath, it's a ServletContext, so you need to use `ServletContext.getResource`.

Problem is, it is not necessary a file: it can be an entry in a WAR archive. So depending on what exactly you know, the answer may be different.

We use a Spring utility class which handles both files (via `ServletContext.getResourcePaths` if available) and WARs (via `ServletContext.getResource`). If you use Spring, that may be the best way. If you don't, you'll probably need to re-implement the solution.

Alternatively, you cal simply use `ServletContext.getResourceAsStream`—it doesn't care where exactly the resource is stored. So as long as you need its content and not the path, you should be fine.

Comment: Yeah, so the thing is that I need this to work inside of and outside of a servlet container. I need a pretty standard API which will let me get a given path whether I'm in Tomcat or in Eclipse's jUnit classpath. What's this API you're using? I'm using Spring 3.

Comment: If you need it outside the container, keep resources in the classpath, and do not touch the Servlet API.

Comment: Using Spring's `ResourceLoader`/`ApplicationContext` to load files. Awesomeness :)

Answer (score 7):

No, it won't resolve.  `Class.getResource` loads resources from the classpath, and the webapp's root directory is not itself on the classpath.

In order to get hold of that resource, you'll need to get hold of the `ServletContext`, on which you can then call `ServletContext.getResource("/WEB-INF/reports/info.txt")`. That should work.

You can obtain the `ServletContext` using `Servlet.getServletConfig().getServletContext()`.

Alternatively, move your `reports` directory under the `/WEB-INF/classes` directory (which *is* on the classpath). You can then get your file using

```
getClass().getResource("reports/info.txt");
```