# Unable to use Rythm template engine with servlet 3.0

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, servlet-3.0, rythm

I am trying to use Rythm templating engine with servlet 3.0 on tomcat7.
I want to render template from `WebContent` directory to `Rythm` engine. But it is not detecting the template.

In servlet `init()` method I initialized Rthym engine as

```
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        Map <String, Object> context = new HashMap <String, Object> ();
        //String filePath = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
        //filePath.concat("WebContent");
        context.put("home.template", "WebContent");
        Rythm.init(context);
    }
```

then I tried to render my `NewFile.html` with `Rythm.render` in `doGet` method as

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Map <String, Object> args = new HashMap <String, Object> ();
        args.put("a", "World");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println(Rythm.render("NewFile.html", args));
    }
```

But it is showing just "NewFile.html" in browser (Not content of NewFile.html but only String "NewFile.html"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue with Rythm and in my case it helped to write the directory in front of the filename:

```
Rythm.render("templates/" + templateFileName, parameters);
```

Setting the `home.template` variable didn't work for me too.

Comment: Any idea why is it so?

Comment: Maybe it is a bug in Rythm.

Answer (score 0):

Rythm loads template files with resource manager. The default implementation of resource manager delegates the resource loading to `Thread.currentThread.getContextClassLoader()`, which can not load any resources under `webapp` folder. See [Resolving the root of a webapp from getResource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749969/resolving-the-root-of-a-webapp-from-getresource).

If you want to load templates under `webapp` folder, you need to create your own resource manager and delegate to `ServletContext` to load template.

Fortunately you don't need to do that. Just put your templates under `resources` folder and then it will just work as expected. Here is a simple project proved it:

[image]

The project source code can be found at https://github.com/greenlaw110/rythm-gh-issue-241